# RequiredFieldValidator not see text has been set by javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik, requiredfieldvalidator, radtextbox

I have a telerik RadTextBox related with `RequiredFieldValidator` in my ASP.NET page. The problem is that when I assign a value to the RadTextBox by javascript, like this:

```
    document.getElementById('<%= mytextbox.ClientID %>').value = myvalue;
```

the validator behaves as if the RadTextBox is still empty and prevents the submit action.

this problem not appear if I use the normal textbox.

Why is this happening and how can i prevent it?

Comment: did you try to see the value of the text after you set it up? make sure its not empty

Comment: it is empty, how to solve?

Comment: try in chrome developer tool.  document.getElementById('<%= mytextbox.ClientID %>') whats the result of this one?

Answer (score 0):

Whether the value of the textbox gets filled by a person or by JavaScript should make no difference to an ASP.NET validator.  What I suspect is happening here is that the snippet of script you provided is being executed before the page is fully loaded.  Try replacing the snippet of script you provided with this one.

```
window.onload = function() {
    var myvalue = 'some test value';
    document.getElementById('<%= mytextbox.ClientID %>').value = myvalue;
};
```

As qamar mentioned in his comment you should see "some test value" in the HTML input field generated by your ASP.NET TextBox.

Comment: the same issue by your code, and I think that is right what you are talking about the html input field generated is empty, but how to solve this issue?

Comment: interesting.  would you be willing to share the full aspx, relavent JS, and codebehind?  that would make it easier for a SO user to duplicate and solve the problem, even though it might be a lot of code to post.  thanks in advance.